# What are the consequences of compiling for an older Java version?

Tags: java, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

I'm trying to make a simple game in Java and sent a very basic draft of the GUI to a couple friends. They had to install the latest JDK to be able to run the `.jar`, since what I had made (using the latest JDK) could not run on Java 8, which is what came installed on their systems.

I already know I can tell the IDE (I'm using NetBeans) to compile for Java 8, but are there any repercussions for doing so, particularly for someone using a more recent version of Java?

What about on my end, am I restricted in what I can use? And if so, will the IDE warn me when I try to use features that weren't available in the older version? Are there any performance or safety issues I should keep in mind?

Alternatively, is there a better way of ensuring backwards compatibility other than just telling the IDE to compile for an older version of Java?

Comment: "am I restricted in what I can use?" yes, for instance you will be prohibited from using API not accessible in older versions, like `List.of(1,2,3)` which was added in Java 9. "will the IDE warn me when I try to use features that weren't available in the older version?" yes it should.

Comment: There's the _consequence_ of less language features, but the _benefit_ that it can be run on the language level you compile for _or later_. Generally you'll want to aim for LTS builds (Java 8, Java 11, Java 17 at the moment).

Comment: What about safety and performance concerns? Will a user who's running Java 17, for instance, be subjected to the performance and safety issues of Java 8 because the code was compiled for Java 8? Is there no better way to achieve backwards compatibility than this?

Comment: Alternatively, you could bundle a JDK with your app, enabling you to use the latest version of Java without concern for what the user may or may not have installed.  See the Java JEPs for *jlink* and *jpackage*.

Comment: Note that a Java 17 JVM will have the security and patch fixes of... a Java 17 JVM. The compiled java project will essentially be "running" in that context, which mostly relies on the API not changing significantly (e.g. `ConcurrentHashMap`'s snafu from Java 7 -> Java 8). You'll get the performance of a Java 17 JVM if that's what they're running as well. Your project just notes what to use, but the JVM will be supplying the core `java.*` features.